# The program in swift is comparing the total with entered value, the answer either correct or try again

Tags: swift, compare

What happing is when I press the Deal button, the answer as if for next random number and not the current one but if the number repeated itself I got the right answer! Can you please help me with this issue? Thanks,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var entreAnswer: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Deal(_ sender: Any) {
        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(5)+1

        text.text = "\(randomNumber)"// display random number in label

        switch randomNumber {
        case 0...6:
            total.text = "\(randomNumber * 10)"
            if total.text == entreAnswer.text{
                print ("correct")
            }
            else{
                entreAnswer.text = "try again"
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of the `switch` statement? `randomNumber` will always be in the range 1...5.

Comment: Hi, This is what I thought but just can't take the entered value in textfield as a correct answer instead ask me to try again

Comment: The switch statement is to choose the right random number

Comment: Replace the entire `switch` statement with just the contents of the `case` statement.

Comment: Do the comparison before creating a new random number and dont forget to provide a random number in viewDidLoad method

Comment: I used if statement at the beginning which git me the same result, then I change it to switch to make the program a bit shorter. On the other hand, I might expand my entries more than 5. Thanks

Comment: If you don't show the rest of your logic we can only guess. The only think I can say right now it that you shouldn't randomize a new number before checking the result

Comment: I'm lost at what you are trying to do. I could hope your code would be of help, but no - you're setting `randomNumber` (got it) then checking if it's between 1 and 6. Got it. But `entireAnswer`? It's likely a language problem in your description of things. Still, forgive me, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: Leo can you please tell me how to provide the random number in viewDidLoad? Regarding the rest of my logic: There are two labels one show you the random number and the other shows you the total number(randomNumberx10) and mt entered value is going to the textfield and this is all what I have. Cheers,

Comment: It is not entireAnswer, it is entreAnswer. All that I'm doing is to compare a total which I get it from randomNumderx10 with entered one. Later I'm going to hide the total box and entering my answer.

Comment: Thanks Leo! The problem has been solved by putting the comparison first.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy by pointing to me that no need to use switch statement :)